# Nginx Amplify failed to report access and error logs

Tags: nginx, monitoring, centos7, process-monitoring

Nginx amplify is reporting the system metrics on centos 7 but it is unable to get metrics from access and error logs. Both the files have permissions for nginx to read and write. The same setup is working fine in Ubuntu. Can someone guide me through this.

Here is the block for nginx_amplify

```
location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow <pvt IP>/32;
                deny all;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a fix for this, we need to make sure that the

```
location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow <pvt IP>/32;
                deny all;
        }
```

block is inside the server block. Do this and restart nginx